# mandar mensaje de error por jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net

```
   function md_ProcesoCierre_Click() {
                var IDColumna = ObtenerIDFilaSeleccionada();
                if (IDColumna == "") {
                    ShowAlertMaster('Warning', 'Validacion del sistema', 'Debe seleccionar una fila para poder iniciar el proceso de cierre', '');
                } else {
                 /*   $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_upProgressGVSCierreVirtuales").css("display", "inline");*/
                    var IDShipper = $('#' + IDColumna + 'HFIDShipper').val();
                   
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "MonitorShippers.aspx/GuardarProcesoCierre",
                        data: '{IDShipper: ' + IDShipper + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (obj) {
                            PageMethods.GuardarProcesoCierre(
                                IDShipper.value,
                                Guardar_Resultados)
                            function Guardar_Resultados(resultado) {
                                if (confirm("¿Está seguro de inciar el proceso de cierre?")) {
                                    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_HFIDShipper').val($('#' + IDColumna + 'HFIDShipper').val());
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            console.log("entere a funcion guardar");
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
```

hola, que tal, tengo una duda es que quiero mostrar un msj en un modal por si me sale un error o si se envió correctamente el proceso, pero no me sale el msj, me hace todo el proceso normal manda el registro en la bd, pero no me muestra ningún msj

Comment: En el código proporcionado, parece que estás utilizando jQuery y AJAX para enviar una solicitud al servidor y ejecutar la función GuardarProcesoCierre en el código del servidor. A continuación, se ejecuta una función llamada Guardar_Resultados como parte del éxito de la solicitud AJAX. Aquí hay algunas sugerencias para solucionar el problema de mostrar el mensaje en un modal: - Verifica que el método GuardarProcesoCierre en el código del servidor está devolviendo la respuesta esperada. Puedes colocar un punto de interrupción o imprimir un mensaje de depuración en el código del servidor para as